# duplicate error in mongodb

Tags: java, mongodb, duplicates

Below is my db collection  in MongoDB named region which contains client field  (marked as bold):

Region collection sample data:

```
{
    "_id": ObjectId("578715205c3c3c325c6e446a"),
    "_class": "com.datiot.common.domain.Region",
    "**client**": {
        "_id": ObjectId("578714e65c3c3c325c6e4468"),
        "name": "Test Client",
        "regions": []
    },
    "contactPerson": "CheckingClientIdtest",
    "***regionName***": "NorthIndia",
    "address": " south delhi"
}
```

in my program i am trying to save region collection but i dont want duplicate region name field (marked bold & italic) against a same client .

please suggest how to achieve this in java?

Comment: Can you please add a sample of data that you consider a duplicate?

Comment: "regionName" : "NorthIndia", "regionName" : "SouthIndia", "regionName" : "NorthIndia", the above should not happen . No two same region names for same Client ID  Noth india is repeated above

Comment: It's not a mongo issue. You need to filter duplicates before you insert